# Use Azure Active Directory for authentication with MySQL in PHP Application

Tags: php, mysql, azure, mysqli

I have been searching all over the place but everything I see about this concerns implementing JWT token authentication for a REST API written in PHP which isn't the question I need answered.  I'm looking to understand something a little simpler.

I have a PHP application written in PHP 7, let's say that I want to connect to a Azure Database for MySQL instance that has Azure Active Directory support enabled.  To my understanding, applications would make use of a JWT token to connect to the Azure Database for MySQL instance, but I have not been able to find an example of how this is done for PHP or if it is even supported by something like mysqli.  I have seen [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication#compatibility-with-application-drivers) which leads me to believe that there is not a supported PHP driver for connecting in this way.

Does anybody know if this is actually supported for PHP?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: That's part of the impetus for the question, I haven't been able to try it.  I am working with an existing azure MySQL instance, there's been a request to see if Azure AD could be enabled on this instance, I'm trying to establish whether doing this will break the PHP applications connecting to the instance or not.